# Test Android in-app purchases with multiple applicationId flavors?

Tags: android, in-app-billing, android-productflavors, in-app-subscription, package-name

The app I'm working on needs to have 3 variants (dev, QA, live) each with different application IDs, so testers can have multiple variants simultaneously installed. I implemented the above using flavors, but now the dev and QA builds no longer receive the app's subscriptions skuDetails when calling [querySkuDetailsAsync()](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/BillingClient#querySkuDetailsAsync(com.android.billingclient.api.SkuDetailsParams,%20com.android.billingclient.api.SkuDetailsResponseListener)), only the live flavor works. Is there any way I can make in-app purchases work for all 3 flavors, while still being able to install multiple flavors simultaneously in the same device?

build.gradle flavor config:

```
flavorDimensions  "client", "server"
productFlavors {
    dev {
        dimension "client"
        versionNameSuffix "-dev"
        applicationIdSuffix ".dev"
    }
    qa {
        dimension "client"
        versionNameSuffix "-qa"
        applicationIdSuffix ".qa"
    }
    live {
        dimension "client"
    }
    prod {
        dimension "server"
    }
    mock {
        dimension "server"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible as `applicationIdSuffix`, makes the `packageName` different to what the IAP's signature is looking for ie. prod signed variant, so even if you prod sign any other variant, you will get an empty list of `SKUs`